# How do i delete previous circles when i decrease the scale of the circle?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a scale using tkinter to increase the size of the circle. I am facing a problem whereby when I decrease the scale of the circle, the previous circle remains. Therefore, is there any method to delete those previous circle?
And FYI, I am using python 2.7.18

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Elastic collision animation')

canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()

def redraw(a):
    ball_1 = True 
    canvas.delete(ball_1) 
    canvas.create_oval(posn_x, posn_y, posn_x+ball_width+int(a),
                       posn_y+ball_height+int(a), fill='blue')
    canvas.update()  

posn_x = 50
posn_y = 50

ball_width = 10
ball_height = 10

ball_1 = canvas.create_oval(posn_x, posn_y, posn_x+ball_width,
                            posn_y+ball_height, fill='blue')

var = IntVar()
scale_1 = Scale(root, label='mass of ball 1', orient=HORIZONTAL, length=200,
                width=15, from_=1, to= 100, variable = var, command=redraw)
scale_1.pack()



root.mainloop()
```

[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RqRX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Elastic collision animation')

canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()

def redraw(a):
    global ball_1
    canvas.delete(ball_1)
    ball_1 = canvas.create_oval(posn_x, posn_y, posn_x+ball_width+int(a),
                                posn_y+ball_height+int(a), fill='blue')

posn_x = 50
posn_y = 50

ball_width = 10
ball_height = 10

ball_1 = canvas.create_oval(posn_x, posn_y, posn_x+ball_width,
                            posn_y+ball_height, fill='blue')

var = IntVar()
scale_1 = Scale(root, label='mass of ball 1', orient=HORIZONTAL, length=200,
                width=15, from_=1, to= 100, variable = var, command=redraw)
scale_1.pack()



root.mainloop()
```

I have no idea why you had `ball_1 = True`. All I did was remove that line and assign the newly created ball id to `ball_1`